Pinescript to modify Chart's day opening first candle
On day opening on any chart, i want first candle's body, color and wick according to previous day last candle close like if it is a continuation from previous day. for example next days first candle opening should be from the point where last day candle was closed. in short i don't want gap up/down opening to  affect the chart.
Tried the following script but some problem is there.
Probable solutions could be

either first candle should be transparent completely so that only indicator candle is plotted and correctly.
indicator must override the first candle OHLC completely.
when indicator is active chart should be hidden.

//@version=5
indicator("No gaps candles", overlay=true)

applyToDayOpenOnly = input(true, title="Apply to day open only")
dayChangeHourThreshold = input(6, title="Hour threshold to detect the day open")
showPriceLine = input(true, title="Show price line")

hoursSinceLastCandle = (time[0] - time[1]) / 1000 / 60 / 60

myOpen = open
myClose = close
myHigh = high
myLow = low

if not applyToDayOpenOnly or hoursSinceLastCandle > dayChangeHourThreshold
    myOpen := close[1]
    myClose := close
    myHigh := high
    myLow := low

candleColor = myOpen <= myClose ? color.teal : color.red

plotcandle(myOpen, myHigh, myLow, myClose, color=candleColor, bordercolor=candleColor, wickcolor=candleColor)

if barstate.islast
    if showPriceLine
        line.new(bar_index - 4999, close, bar_index + 500, close, color=candleColor, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)

Click here for Example
As shown in image, dark colored part should be wick but it is also visible as candle body that is the Problem.

this is confusing. Could you post a screenshot?

Example image is shared just below the code.

I'm still confused. Maybe my answer is not what you are looking for...
Try session.isfirstbar
something like that:
//@version=5
indicator("No gaps candles", overlay=true)

myOpen = open
myClose = close
myHigh = high
myLow = low

if session.isfirstbar
    myOpen := close[1]
    myClose := close
    myHigh := high
    myLow := low

candleColor = myOpen <= myClose ? color.teal : color.red

plotcandle(myOpen, myHigh, myLow, myClose, color=candleColor, bordercolor=candleColor, wickcolor=candleColor)

bgcolor(
  session.isfirstbar ? color.new(color.gray, 90) : na,
  title      = 'isfirstbar')

image test

Is there any way to hide the original chart or make the original chart completely transparent when this indicator is active.

try barcolor
